# Global json object in java

Tags: java, json, global-variables

Is there any way to declare global json object in Java?

```
public class Constants {
    public static JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    static {
        jsonObject.put("name","Raju");
        jsonObject.put("age",21);
    }
}
```

Other than this, is there any other way to declare it?

Comment: There is an infinite number of ways, so you'll have to be more specific than "any other way". What precisely do you want to see changed?

Comment: [Global variables in Java](//stackoverflow.com/q/4646577)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.